# Synchronize cursor position in kile

Tags: kile, live-preview

I recently started using Kile on Windows.

I haven't faced any problems in the installation and even the live preview feature is working without any problems.

The problem I am facing is the live preview instead of showing the present working line, it is positioning itself to the top of the document.

I even tried switching off the live preview and preview using compilation + embedded viewer. But still it is showing the top part of the document I am editing instead of the page I am typing now.

Comment: This is normal. I think it is the intended behaviour.  Build > View > ForwardPDF or ForwardDVI are probably what you want.

Comment: I tried that. But same problem. I tried installing kile(windows) on my friends laptop and it was working perfectly on his.

Comment: Have you tried with the non-embedded viewer? I only ask because I use neither live preview nor the embedded viewer. (But I also don't use Windows.)

Comment: I tried that also. I don't it is a problem of live preview, because even when I disable and use it normally, instead of showing the recent change in the document, it is going to the top of the document in the preview.